# Bug in java.util.regex in sun jdk 6.0.24?

Tags: java, regex

The following code blocks on my system. Why?

```
System.out.println( Pattern.compile( 
   "^((?:[^'\"][^'\"]*|\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*')*)/\\*.*?\\*/(.*)$", 
   Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL ).matcher( 
   "\n\n\n\n\n\nUPDATE \"$SCHEMA\" SET \"VERSION\" = 12 WHERE NAME = 'SOMENAMEVALUE';"
   ).matches() );
```

The pattern (designed to detect comments of the form `/*...*/` but not within `'` or `"`) should be fast, as it is deterministic...
Why does it take soooo long?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're running into [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Looking at your regex, it's easy to see how `.*?` and `(.*)` can match the same content since both also can match the intervening `\*/` part (dot matches all, remember). Plus (and even more problematic), they can also match the same stuff that `((?:[^'"][^'"]*|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*)` matches.

The regex engine gets bogged down in trying all the permutations, especially if the string you're testing against is long.

I've just checked your regex against your string in [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com). It aborts the match attempt after 1.000.000 steps of the regex engine. Java will keep churning on until it gets through all permutations or until a Stack Overflow occurs...

You can greatly improve the performance of your regex by prohibiting backtracking into stuff that has already been matched. You can use [atomic groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) for this, changing your regex into

```
^((?>[^'"]+|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*)(?>/\*.*?\*/)(.*)$
```

or, as a Java string:

```
"^((?>[^'\"]+|\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*')*)(?>/\\*.*?\\*/)(.*)$"
```

This reduces the number of steps the regex engine has to go through from > 1 million to 58.

Be advised though that this will only find the first occurrence of a comment, so you'll have to apply the regex repeatedly until it fails.

Edit: I just added two slashes that were important for the expressions to work. Yet I had to change more than 6 characters.... :(

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know about atomic groups at all. After adding two slashes (one per format), your solution works. Best regards, Steffen

Comment: I don't know, why I did not notice last year, but that expression does not match `"TEST /* A */ TEST"` for example, because the first / ist already bound by the atomic group. I had to change it to `"^((?:(?>[^'\"/]+|\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*')|/)*)(?>/\\*.*?\\*/)(.*)$"`. If somone has an optimization idea, feel welcome...

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you read [Regular Expression Matching Can Be Simple And Fast (but is slow in Java, Perl, PHP, Python, Ruby, ...)](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html).

Comment: I'd check to see if the arguments still apply.  It isn't like all of those languages haven't changed or optimized certain items over the last four years.  It's also not clear if it is a fair comparison, the PCRE solution stops backtracking at 23 iterations, which means it theoretically might miss solutions.

Comment: Even when the article was written, some of those languages included ways to effectively impose deterministic behavior.  Java has always supported atomic groups and possessive quantifiers; Perl and PCRE support those plus [backtracking-control verbs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Special-Backtracking-Control-Verbs) for finer control; Ruby is now powered by the [Oniguruma](http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/doc/RE.txt) library, so it has atomic groups and possessive quantifiers, too.  Of course, users have to know about those features, and learn how to use them...

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of this bit:

```
(?:[^'\"][^'\"]*|\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*')*
```

Removing the second and third alternatives gives you:

```
(?:[^'\"][^'\"]*)*
```

or:

```
(?:[^'\"]+)*
```

Repeated repeats can take a long time.

Comment: That's not the problem. Neither of those alternatives can match anything that one of the others can, so repeating this is fast. Since one of them always matches, there is no backtracking. However, the parts that follow in the regex *will* cause catastrophic backtracking.

Answer (score 0):

For comment `/*` and `*/` detection I would suggest having a code like this:

```
String str = "\n\n\n\n\n\nUPDATE \"$SCHEMA\" /*a comment\n\n*/ SET \"VERSION\" = 12 WHERE NAME = 'SOMENAMEVALUE';";
Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'|(/\\*.*?\\*/)", 
                             Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher = pt.matcher(str);
boolean found = false;
while (matcher.find()) {
   if (matcher.group(1) != null) {
      found = true;
      break;
   }
}
if (found)
   System.out.println("Found Comment: [" + matcher.group(1) + ']');
else
   System.out.println("Didn't find Comment");
```

For above string it prints:

```
Found Comment: [/*a comment

*/]
```

But if I **change** input string to:

```
String str = "\n\n\n\n\n\nUPDATE \"$SCHEMA\" '/*a comment\n\n*/' SET \"VERSION\" = 12 WHERE NAME = 'SOMENAMEVALUE';";
```

OR

```
String str = "\n\n\n\n\n\nUPDATE \"$SCHEMA\" \"/*a comment\n\n*/\" SET \"VERSION\" = 12 WHERE NAME = 'SOMENAMEVALUE';";
```

**Output** is:

```
Didn't find Comment
```